# Blender Script Rotate All

Tags: scripting

I am making a script that needs to rotate everything on the Z axis, this is what I have come up with.

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')    
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=(3.14), constraint_axis=(False, False, True))
```

I get an error that the object has no value rot, so my question, how do I rotate everything via a script, do I have to run a loop through everything?

Comment: it should be  `value = (0, 0, 3.14)` , what does your selection include ?

Comment: Oh ok, I was looking at the blender wiki and it seemed unclear on how I was supposed to do the rotation. I assumed that you had to put in a value and then specify the axis you wanted rotated by this value.

Comment: so is it working now ?

Comment: I don't know, I'll try and post a comprehensive answer on the subject once I test it, I have to build other sections of code in c++ to load what I'm making into my program.